# If first input is focused write there else to second one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make for example If first input `.res` is focused write there else on `.res2` I tried this firstly `.res` is focused then when you click buttons which are into `.operators` div focus moves to second input `.res2` but it doesnt work

```
$(".one,.two,.three,.four,.five,.six,.seven,.eight,.nine,.zero,.dot").click(function(){
            if($('.res').is(":focus")){
                firstNumber = $('.res').val(($('.res').val()) + $(this).val());
            } else {
                secondNumber = $('.res2').val(($('.res2').val()) + $(this).val());
            }
        })
$(".plus,.subtract,.divide,.multiply").click(function(){
            resultWindow.blur();
            $('.res2').focus();
        })
```

```html
        <div id="calculator">
            <div class="wind">
                <input class="res" value=" " maxlength="24">
                <input class="res2" value=" " maxlength="24">
            <div class="numbers">
                <button class="one" value="1">1</button>
                <button class="two" value="2">2</button>
                <button class="three" value="3">3</button>
                <br>
                <button class="four" value="4">4</button>
                <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
                <button class="six" value="6">6</button>
                <br>
                <button class="seven" value="7">7</button>
                <button class="eight" value="8">8</button>
                <button class="nine" value="9">9</button>
                <br>
                <button class="zero" value="0">0</button>
                <button class="dot" value=".">.</button>
            </div>
            <div class="operators">
                <button class="plus">+</button>
                <button class="subtract">-</button>
                <button class="divide">/</button>
                <button class="multiply">*</button>
                <button class="equal">=</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that every time you click the button, the input blurs and the button gains focus.

So, `$('.res').is(":focus")` will always return `false`.

To achieve this, you need to add another event listener to prevent the default behavior of the button clicks:

```
$("button").mousedown(function(e) {e.preventDefault()})
```

Also, I'd recommend to use this query selector:

```
$(".numbers > button")
$(".operators > button")
```

So, your code looks simpler.

Take a look how it works:

```js
$("button").mousedown(function(e) {e.preventDefault()})
$(".numbers > button").click(function() {
  if ($('.res').is(":focus")) {
    firstNumber = $('.res').val(($('.res').val()) + $(this).val());
  } else {
    secondNumber = $('.res2').val(($('.res2').val()) + $(this).val());
  }
})
$(".operators > button").click(function() {
  resultWindow.blur();
  $('.res2').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calculator">
  <div class="wind">
    <input class="res" value=" " maxlength="24">
    <input class="res2" value=" " maxlength="24">
    <div class="numbers">
      <button class="one" value="1">1</button>
      <button class="two" value="2">2</button>
      <button class="three" value="3">3</button>
      <br>
      <button class="four" value="4">4</button>
      <button class="five" value="5">5</button>
      <button class="six" value="6">6</button>
      <br>
      <button class="seven" value="7">7</button>
      <button class="eight" value="8">8</button>
      <button class="nine" value="9">9</button>
      <br>
      <button class="zero" value="0">0</button>
      <button class="dot" value=".">.</button>
    </div>
    <div class="operators">
      <button class="plus">+</button>
      <button class="subtract">-</button>
      <button class="divide">/</button>
      <button class="multiply">*</button>
      <button class="equal">=</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a mousedown event instead of a click event on your buttons, and then preventing default, which should keep the input from losing focus.

```
$(".one,.two,.three,.four,.five,.six,.seven,.eight,.nine,.zero,.dot").on('mousedown', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('.res').is(":focus")){...}
  ...
});
```

Comment: What would happen if you run this on a mobile browser with no "mouse"?

Comment: most mobile browsers throw click events with the touches, but you could also do it with `.on('mousedown touchstart', function(event) {...});`